# Link button in tree at end of each parent node

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3

I need to have link buttons at end of each parent node as shown below

```
->IBM Machines (rename | delete | disable)
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
->Sony ( rename | delete | disable)
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
```

rename, delete and diasble are link buttons. I have tried with label function and other methods also but not able get the exact requrement. Please help me as how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, you should ideally use an itemrenderer.... for details on itemrenderer for trees , check http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_8.html , under the heading Using item renderer with tree control.

That specifically shows, adding your own custom labels, for parents in a tree control.